# Moving to new Mac, how to move Cocoapods trunk credentials

Tags: cocoapods

First, forgive me as I'm a newbie to Cocoapods/trunks.

I've created a pod recently, and I'm moving to a new Mac (I won't migrate, I'll do a clean install). I know that the credentials to update/push to a trunk is saved with a session key on my Mac. Where is it, and how can I move that to the new Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily start a new session on the new machine by entering `pod trunk register <your@email.address>` which will then send you an email to confirm the session.

Comment: Thanks, just to be sure. Can I use my same mail address? I'm (obviously) not changing my email address so both sessions will be tied to the same email address.

Comment: Yes, use whichever email address you used to register the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new session would work for sure. But to answer your exact question of where the credentials are:

Check out your `~/.netrc` file. There should be a few lines like

```
machine trunk.cocoapods.org
  login <your_email>
  password <secret>
```